# In go - gorm "mssql: Invalid column name 'id'

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

This is my model in go

```
package models

import (
"time"

"gorm.io/gorm"
 )

type VID uint

type CompanyNames struct {
Id   VID    `json:"id,omitempty"`
Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
CreateDate time.Time `json:"CreateDate,omitempty"`
ModifyDate time.Time `json:"ModifyDate,omitempty"`
```

}

and this is my repo(that retrieve data from database):

```
func (m *Repo) Read(id models.VID) (*models.CompanyNames, error) {
var (
    cn = &models.CompanyNames{}
)
err := m.db.Debug().Table("CompanyNames").First(cn, &id).Error

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return cn, err
```

}

On "http" I write this code with echo

```
func NewHttp(e *echo.Group, lg *Logic) {
g := e.Group("/companyname")
g.GET("", readAll)
g.GET("/:Id", read)

logic = lg
}
```

When I cal my ReadAll record rerieve data completly , it's mean I conected to database currectly,But whene I try get data by "id"  got an error that :

> mssql: Invalid column name 'id'.

Whet is my mistake
another hand make id in my struct as a comment like this:>

```
type CompanyNames struct {
//Id   VID    `json:"id,omitempty"`
Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
CreateDate time.Time `json:"CreateDate,omitempty"`
ModifyDate time.Time `json:"ModifyDate,omitempty"`
}
```

got new error that

> mssql: Invalid column name 'name'.
> [2690.814ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "CompanyNames" WHERE "CompanyNames"."name" = '1' ORDER BY "CompanyNames"."id" OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

***Update:***

func Cunnection() (*gorm.DB, error) {
var (
err error
db  *gorm.DB
)
dsn := "sqlserver://DbUser:mypass@111.111.111.111:1433?database=myDb"

```
db, err = gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
// err = db.Debug().AutoMigrate(&models.CompanyNameModel{})
// if err != nil {
//  return nil, err
// }
return db, nil
```

}

Comment: can you share the database schema being accessed?

Comment: I received data when call Redall function, bun in resd by Iid got that eror

Comment: Uodated my question and add connection to sqldatabase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your own answer, I found your question. As the comments above say, it's easier to find the problem if you show your table structure.

The column name specified by your query is `Id` and your structure does not explicitly specify this name. According to the [Grom convention](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Conventions), your `Id` field will be converted into `id`. This problem can be solved by adding [tags](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags).

For example:

```golang
package models

import (
    "time"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type VID uint

type CompanyNames struct {
    Id   VID    `json:"id,omitempty" gorm:"column:Id"`
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty" gorm:"column:Name"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

two ways for answer after check many ways

first of i must use Find insted of First another hand i try retrieve data by thse two ways

1:

```
err := m.db.Debug().Table("CompanyNames").Find(cn, "Id = ?", id).Error
```

2:

```
err := m.db.Debug().Table("CompanyNames").Find(cn, map[string]interface{}{
    "Id": Id,
}).Error
```

Update :
As @kocoler wrote, I tested and it was currect, also I think ***First*** is beter for performance VS Find
***strong text***
as reserach the beter way is the second way